# Why fountain character matches anchor character in regular expression inside range?

Tags: regex, pcre

In PCRE2 I got a problem with regular expression `/[⚓️]/`. It has match for string `"⛲️"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/42HWXE/1)

Unexpected behaviour persists only inside range.

Can somebody explain why is this happening?

By the way, PCRE1 works just fine: no matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `⚓️` emoji is a sequence of two Unicode code points: `\x{2693}\x{FE0F}`. You can test it and see that `\x{2693}\x{FE0F}` regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/tPFTay/1) `⚓️`.

When you place the `\x{2693}\x{FE0F}` into a character class, you [find a match](https://regex101.com/r/tPFTay/2) in both `⛲️` (=`\x{26F2}\x{FE0F}`) and `⚓️` since both contain at least one of the Unicode code points.

As a workaround, place the emojis into a non-capturing group rather than a character class, e.g. `(?:⚓️|[a-z0-9])` will match a `⚓️` or a lowercase ASCII letter/digit.

Comment: But why does PCRE1 it behave differently?